# How to run openconnect with username and password in a line in the terminal?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, 18.04, konsole, openconnect

I use `openconnect` in Ubuntu 16.04 terminally, when I want to run it, I need to enter three phases:

- "yes/no"
- "username"
- "password"

How can I bypass above phases using `openconnect` in **a line** (e.g. using `openconnect` options)?
Are there any options for that such as the following line?

```
sudo openconnect <server-name> --user=<'username'> --pass=<'password'>
```

I used `openconnect --help` and found out a way to filling username, but I haven't any idea to filling password and SSL verification.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you type `man openconnect` in a terminal you will get a [manual page describing usage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/openconnect).

Relevant sections:

> -u,--user=NAME
>   Set login username to NAME
>
> --passwd-on-stdin
>   Read password from standard input

Additionally, you may need to disable certificate warnings:

> --no-cert-check
>   Do not require server SSL certificate to be valid. Checks will still happen and failures will cause a warning message, but the connection will continue anyway. You should not need to use this option - if your servers have SSL certificates which are not signed by a trusted Certificate Authority, you can still add them (or your private CA) to a local file and use that file with the --cafile option.

Or you could add the certificate to a file.

All this can be combined:

```
echo "password" | sudo openconnect server --user=username --passwd-on-stdin --no-cert-check
```

Comment: The answer above is still correct except for `--no-cert-check` which has been removed due to security risks. This is the error message now when using it: The --no-cert-check option was insecure and has been removed. Fix your server's certificate or use --servercert to trust it. (can't comment above because not enough points; mods feel free to clear this up)

Comment: Seems like if they prompt for 2FA it goofs up the response code if you do --passwd-on-stdn

Answer (score 8):

I was able to automate both sudo password, VPN user, VPN password and secondary challenge using the following command (tested on mac):

```
challange=<code> && sudo -S <<< "<sudo_password>" echo I am super user && { printf '<vpn_password>\n'; sleep 1; printf "$challange\n"; } | sudo openconnect <server_name> --user <vpn_username> --passwd-on-stdin
```

Comment: What's the <code>?

Comment: `<code>` is some code/number you get from a 2-Factor Authentication (2FA) service. In my case its a smartphone application with some rotating number.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine with my MFA.
One change that I made was, create a sh file and pass the MFA code as an arg to it
Change in script: `challange="$1"
ScriptName: vpn.sh
terminal: ./vpn,sh <code>

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. For me, nothing worked, including recording and modifying script through autoexpect, I even tried putting together a pexpect python script, nothing worked. This is was the only thing out of many worked. I automated to MFA challenge with a script, and now this is fully automated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
echo mypassword | openconnect --protocol=anyconnect --user=myusername --passwd-on-stdin
```

Comment: yep, this works if the server does not require a certificate. You can also omit `--protocol=anyconnect` since it's the default value anyway.

Answer (score 4):

To skip the certificate check, The `--no-cert-check` parameter was removed in new versions. You can use `--servercert` instead.

`--servercert sha256:sdflkdsjflsdjkfds`

Comment: Actually, I don't have any server certification, in this new version how can I bypass it?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari when you run that command, the openconnect gives you an error message that contains `Server SSL certificate didn't match: pin-sha256:76v/J0dQR44xdeBCxKUq/Slvtikc+0xTyRdjaZk/5fA=` the `pin-sha256:76v/J0dQR44xdeBCxKUq/Slvtikc+0xTyRdjaZk/5fA=` is your servercert.

Comment: @SdSaati Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 4):

As I read the solutions, finally this is the script that is working for me:

```bsh
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo openconnect --protocol=anyconnect SERVER --user=USERNAME --passwd-on-stdin --servercert SERVERCERT
```

When you run the above command without SERVERCERT(**because you don't have it**), it gives an **error** to you that contains the SERVERCERT inside it, something like:
`Server SSL certificate didn't match: pin-sha256:76v/J0dQR44xdeBCxKUq/Slvtikc+0xTyRdjaZk/5fA=`
and that's it, the string started with pin-sha256:...(the whole of it, include pin-sha256 itself) is your SERVERCERT

So? the final result in this case for example is:

```bsh
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo openconnect --protocol=anyconnect SERVER --user=USERNAME --passwd-on-stdin --servercert pin-sha256:76v/J0dQR44xdeBCxKUq/Slvtikc+0xTyRdjaZk/5fA=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this very easy to use shell script: https://github.com/sorinipate/vpn-up-for-openconnect

From the project's description:

> ## vpn-up-for-openconnect
>
> VPN Up for OpenConnect
>
> ### Features
>
> A shell script for openconnect which allows:
>
> - to define multiple VPN connections
> - to run openconnect without entering the username and password.
>
> ### Sample configuration section
>
> ```
> #Company VPN
> export COM_NAME="My Company VPN"
> export COM_HOST=vpn.mycompany.com
> export COM_AUTHGROUP=developers
> export COM_USER=sorin.ipate
> export COM_PASSWD="MyPassword"
> ```
>
> ### Run VPN Up
>
> ```
> % alias vpn-up='~/bin/vpn-up.command'
> % vpn-up
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "YourPassword" | sudo openconnect vpn.yourserver.com --user=yourUseraname --passwd-on-stdin
```

- For me password needs `"` `"`
- In the latest version `--no-cert-check` is deprecated from the command argument by openconnect (my version: OpenConnect version v7.08-3ubuntu0.18.04.2)